# Unknown item in macOS screen time, is it malware?

Tags: macos, mac, malware, screen-time

I checked my screen time after a few weeks today and saw that it said 24 hours and it seems more than half of that was something called "psv4.userapi.com". My Mac is usually asleep for most of the time and some safari and other app windows are open. I was worried so I tried visiting the website using a VPN and with my antivirus active and it gave me an error page for some sort of shady Russian social media, I think. I ran a scan on Avast and it didn't seem to detect anything but this is obviously not normal can anyone please help? my Mac is an early 2015 Macbook air running Big Sur 11.4 as of now.

edit: I've figured out that the domain is the same as the one from where videos were embedded on an anime website I used a little while ago, i've deleted any downloads from it and cleared my caches. I do not know if it'll fix the problem if it doesn't I'll do a backup from way before I had this issue. any further help is really appreciated

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known, common bug in the Screen Time application.  It's been around for a few years and it doesn't look like Apple is in any hurry to fix it.

The URL is displayed because it was running in Safari while you were viewing videos.

If you're really concerned about it, or embarassing sites are displayed, just [delete the Safari cache and history](https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/clear-your-browsing-history-sfri47acf5d6/mac), they'll go away.

Comment: thanks! I did this and it works now! I was worried for a second

Comment: Can you expand on the “why” part? So, if I watch a video from a site, it’ll plague my Screen Time until I clear Safari’s history and data?

Comment: @ColeJohnson I don't know the 'why' part as Apple hasn't released info on why this happens.  It occurs periodically with all different kinds of content, mostly websites but there's been some apps.